# Weird mouse behaviour in Xubuntu - BUG?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, xubuntu, mouse, debugging

I have Xubuntu 14.04 x64 installed and I'm noticing a very strange behaviour. *Sometimes* my mouse acts as if I've pressed the right button and opens context menus at random.

I've tried finding out where the problem is coming from, but had no success. Here's what I was able to find out so far:

- It happens with both USB and PS/2 devices, because I tried with 2 different devices that work correctly in other computer (also with linux, but Ubuntu 14.04 x64 rather than Xubuntu);
- It happens in *any* app/program I used so far;
- Seems to happen more often when I'm selecting text, although it doesn't always happen.

The way I see it, it must have something to do with the device driver or something similar, but specific to Xubuntu, **OR** it's a computer hardware problem.

Can anyone share some pointers as to where and how to look for the problem/solution?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to follow the [Ubuntu Mouse Debugging Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingMouseDetection) guide to try and find some info to help out, but I'm not getting very far. My *rogue* right-clicks don't trigger in the event window, and, on the other hand, they aren't logged when triggered somewhere else. The only thing I can extract from this is that if some event actually exists to trigger the context-menu, `xev` doesn't see it.

**EDIT2:** Noted a new symptom: again, *sometimes* after popping a context menu at random, if I try to left-click *outside* the menu, the same context menu appears where I clicked.

**EDIT3:** As I keep digging the internet looking for an answer, I noticed that it *seems* to happen more often (I'm not actually keeping count) on Chromium (48.0.2564.82 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)) and MS Visual Studio Code (0.8.0). For instance, in XFCE's Terminal it hasn't happened yet, although in the desktop it happens frequently.

This is driving me nuts! Can someone please help?

Comment: Is it a laptop?

Comment: @Pilot6 no, it's a desktop computer.

Comment: You mentioned *sometimes* it behaves such, then since when this started to occur i.e. since fresh install? Also, have you tried plugging into different USB ports and see any difference?

Comment: @clearkimura yes, this happens since fresh install. Right now I don't think it relates with USB, as it happens also with the PS/2 mouse I'm currently using. It should be a driver or XFCE issue, I think.